# Confusing Javascript property accessors

Tags: javascript

I'm not fully getting this:

```
var one = {};
var two = {};
var three = {};

three[one] = "one";
three[two] = "two";

console.log(three[one]); // Alerts "two"
```

As I understand it, JS needs a string inside the bracket property notation. So it looks like JS is trying to change:

```
three[one] = "one";
three[two] = "two";
```

into:

```
three[one.toString()] = "one";
three[two.toString()] = "two";
```

Both toString() methods aren't defined so they end up being the same value?
Not sure if I get it.

Comment: The `.toString()` method comes from the Object prototype. Try typing `({}).toString()` in your browser console.

Comment: You are essentially just using the key `[object Object]`.. you are setting the value: `three["[object Object]"] = "one";`, then overwriting that to 'two', and then accessing that overwritten value.

Comment: "[object Object]" with quotes that is.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: @Josh Crozier Thanks for your clarity. It looks like my intuition was on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the toString method is defined and results in the same string for both(`[object Object]`).

```js
var one = {};
var two = {};
$('body').append(one.toString()+'<br>'+two.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var one = {};
var two = {};
var three = {};

three[one] = "one";
three[two] = "two";
```

The last two lines are saying:

```
three[object] = "one";
three[object] = "two";
```

Because one and two are both declared as objects.

The three object that you're making is going to look like this:

```
[object Object] {
  [object Object]: "two"
}
```